# Foreach não retorna valor nenhum

Tags: php, json

Tenho uma `API` que me retorna alguns resultados, porém com ajuda de vocês consegui fazer o código funcionar mas após uns dias o código parou.

Tenho este código:

```
<?php
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $nome  = $_GET['nome'];

    //Não mexer//
    require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; 
        use Intercom\IntercomClient;
            $client = new IntercomClient('App_ID', 'App_Key');
    //Não mexer//
$client->leads->create(["email" => $email]);
    sleep(40);

    //Pega dados Lead//
        $leads = $client->leads->getLeads(['email' => $email]); 

        foreach($leads->contacts as $contact){
            echo "type: " . $contact->type ."<br>";
            echo "id: " . $contact->id ."<br>";
            echo "user_id: " . $contact->user_id ."<br>";
            echo "email: " . $contact->email ."<br>";
            echo "name: " . $contact->name ."<br>";
            $id = $contact->id;
        }
    //Termina de Pegar//

    //Cria a Tag//
    $client->tags->tag([
      "name" => "beneficio-em-dobro",
      "users" => [
        ["id" => $id]
      ]
    ]);
    //end//
```

Como podem ver, tenho que dar uma "pausa" de 40 segundos, se não o código não funciona.
Não entendi o por quê, se estava funcionando normalmente.

[Git Hub SDK](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-php) & [Docs](https://developers.intercom.io/docs)

Comment: O Response está demorando a chegar, isso?

Comment: Sim mais o menos, se eu não coloco os **40s** ele retorna um erro imenso de not fund etc..

Answer (score 0):

Tenta declarando as variáveis como null antes do foreach. Habilite o retorno de erro nas variáveis do PHP tb, pode ajudar na solução.

Comment: ....
....
...
$email = "";  
 foreach($leads->contacts as $contact){
            echo "type: " . $contact->type ."<br>";
            echo "id: " . $contact->id ."<br>";
            echo "user_id: " . $contact->user_id ."<br>";
            echo "email: " . $contact->email ."<br>";
            echo "name: " . $contact->name ."<br>";
            $id = $contact->id;
        }